# Achartengine on Android

Tags: android, graph, charts, achartengine

I am using Achartengine to create graph in my app.
I want that my X axes would be a string, for now I am here:

```
public class LineGraph {
    public Intent getIntent(Context context){
        String[] x = { "a", "b" };
        int[] y = { 1 , 2 };

        TimeSeries series = new TimeSeries("Line");
        for(int i = 0; i < x.length; i++){
            series.add(x, y);
        }

        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Did my answer help you? Please accept it if it did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add custom text labels on the X axis this way:

```
renderer.addXTextLabel(x, "text");
```